# Prove $\frac{n}{n+1}<\frac{n+1}{n+2}$

Tags: inequality

How can we prove the following inequality: $$\frac{n}{n+1} < \frac{n+1}{n+2}$$

I understand how to do proof by inductions and contradictions, but I am getting stuck on this question.

My proof would start out with its base case.
$n= 0$;
$0/1 < 1/2$ holds true;

I.H.: this following equality holds true for a natural number $n$.
We must now show that it also holds true for $n+1$:

$$\frac{n+1}{n+2} < \frac{n+2}{n+3}$$

From here I am stuck. We know the first term is greater than $n/n+1$ from our IH, but it gives no evidence that $\frac{n+2}{n+3}$ is greater than $\frac{n+1}{n+2}$
I see no correlation on how to prove this using the IH. Am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, the induction hypothesis does **not** say "Assume that the [property] holds for **all** natural numbers $n$"; it says "Assume that it holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$". There is a subtle but important difference.

Comment: Very true. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Replace n+1 with m. Then it boils down to showing

$$\frac{m-1}{m} < \frac{m}{m+1} \to m^2 - 1 < m^2$$

QED

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to induction, note that
$$
\frac{n}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}<1-\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $n\ge 0$
$$\frac{n+1}{n+2}-\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)^2-n(n+2)}{(n+2)(n+1)}=\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)}\gt 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another proof "without induction":
$$ n(n + 2) = n^2 + 2n < n^2 + 2n + 1 = (n+1)^2.$$
Divide both sides by $(n + 1)(n + 2)$:
$$ \frac{n}{n + 1} < \frac{n+1}{n+2}.$$

If you want to be a stickler for detail, 
you could use induction to prove the first inequality.